# How to pass a javascript variable into an Each loop (jQuery) on an JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When an object is clicked on a page I am collecting the data from that object and I need to pass that into a jQuery each loop but substitute my JSON object for the data I have.

Here is my HTML

```
<a href="#">Large</a>
```

Here is my JSON Data

```
var sizeArray = {"Large":{"Red":[78],"Blue":[0],"Green":[0]}
```

And finally the JS I'm having a problem with

```
var size = $('a').text();
$.each(sizeArray.size, function(key, val){    
    if(this == 0){
        alert(key);
}});
```

All I'm getting is an error saying "a is undefined" in jQuery. I know the issue is not with jQuery and the issue is with the par that says "sizeArray.size". If I replace the word size with Large than everything works. I just can't figure out how to pass that in!

Comment: you are missing one } at the end of sizeArray definition, but thats probably not the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
$.each(sizeArray[size], function(key, val) { ... });
```

instead.

For more information, check out "[Objects as associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)"